# Firebase can't open on laptop

Tags: firebase, firebase-console

I'm trying to use firebase for first time but the console isn't opening through my google chrome or firefox. I tried to open console through  my mobile it opens but not from laptop.

Answer (score 1):

Open [firebase](https://console.firebase.google.com) site in chrome, then click to inspect option and switch to mobile emulator, and reload the webpage, now you will able to see firebase home page...!

Exit the mobile emulator to see full page.

[see this image for mobile emulator option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQcEw.png)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you haven't logged in on another device.